# golang has pointer's pointer or pointer's reference feature?

Tags: pointers, go

Hi everyone in Golang what will you do if you need to change the pointer (change where the pointer points to rather than change the value where this pointer points to). I know it is really easy in C++ by using reference, like"

```
void myFunc(Type*& ptr)
{
    ptr = anotherPointer;
}

int main
{
    Type* ptr = &someValue;
    myFunc(ptr); // ptr is moved
}
```

Or equivalently in C, use pointer's pointer:

```
void myFunc(Type** ptrsptr)
{
    *ptrsptr = anotherPointer;
}

int main
{
    Type* ptr = &someValue;
    myFunc(&ptr); // ptr is moved
}
```

I wonder if Golang has this neat feature, or if not, the only way is to set at function's return?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a pointer to a pointer, just like in C

http://play.golang.org/p/vE-3otpKkb

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Type struct{}

var anotherPointer = &Type{}

func myFunc(ptrsptr **Type) {
    *ptrsptr = anotherPointer
}

func main() {
    ptr := &Type{}
    fmt.Printf("%p\n", ptr)
    myFunc(&ptr) // ptr is moved
    fmt.Printf("%p\n", ptr)
}
```

Comment: Good answer! But why golang does not adopt the C++ style reference?

Comment: @Jun - because Go isn't C++. Go strives for simple, orthogonal language features.

Answer (score 0):

The below example will change the value of variable only:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

value := 200
var p1 *int = &value

var p2 **int = &p1

fmt.Printf("Value of variable before updating %v and address of pointer is: %p\n", *p1, p1)

*p1 = 300

fmt.Printf("Value of variable after updating by p1 %v and address of pointer is: %p\n", *p1, p1)

**p2 = 400
fmt.Printf("Value of variable after updating by p2 %v and address of pointer is: %p\n", *p1, p1)

}
```

The below code will change the pointer value and also point to new address:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func changePointer(newP **int) {

  val := 500
  *newP = &val

}

func main() {

value := 200
var p1 *int = &value
fmt.Printf("Value of variable before updating %v and address of pointer is: %p\n", *p1, p1)

changePointer(&p1)

fmt.Printf("Value of variable after updating %v and address of pointer is: %p\n", *p1, p1)

 }
```